# How to create SWIG mapping for std::shared_ptr<double> to Java

Tags: java, c++11, swig

What should be the proper SWIG mapping for the following function?

```
std::shared_ptr<double> getMinScale() const;
```

Comment: What is the point of using a `shared_ptr` to a primitive value? Why not simply use `double`? Do you need to be able to write to this value from Java?

Comment: @mmomtchev I cant modify the C++ part. This value should be read and written from Java. `shared_ptr` is used to pass the NULL value.

Comment: Create a typemap for `shared_ptr` that returns a `double`. While you can use a `shared_ptr` in SWIG, if you can avoid it, you will be better off without it.

Answer (score 2):

A very simply solution would be to simply ignore this function and create a Java-compatible wrapper.

(not tested)

```
%ignore std::shared_ptr<double> YourClass::getMinScale() const;

%extend YourClass {
  double getMinScaleJava() const {
    auto r = self->getMinScale();
    return *r;
  }
}
```

If you need the `shared_ptr`, then you will have to use a typemap.

Comment: Thanks, look like a simple solution, I have implemented type mapping approach, which is more complicated but I can pass null types.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following approach using `typemap`.
I convert `std::shared_ptr<double>` into `Double`, which allows passing null value.

```
%typemap(jstype) std::shared_ptr<double> "Double" // C++ to Java type mapping (Java wrapper class)
%typemap(jtype) std::shared_ptr<double> "Double" // C++ to JNI Java type mapping
%typemap(jni)  std::shared_ptr<double> "jobject" // C++ to JNI C++ type mapping (C++ file with JNI code)
%typemap(javain) std::shared_ptr<double> "$javainput" // How Java type is passed to JNI
%typemap(javaout) std::shared_ptr<double> { // How Java type is retrieved from JNI
    return $jnicall;
}

%typemap(in) std::shared_ptr<double> { // How value is passed into C++
    if($input != NULL){
        jclass jcDouble = jenv->FindClass("java/lang/Double");
        jmethodID jmidDoubleValue = jenv->GetMethodID(jcDouble, "doubleValue", "()D");
        double value = jenv->CallDoubleMethod($input,jmidDoubleValue);
        $1 = std::make_shared<double>(value);
    }else{
        $1 = NULL;
    }
}

%typemap(out) std::shared_ptr<double> { //How value is retrieved from C++
    jclass dClass = jenv->FindClass("java/lang/Double");
    jmethodID initInt = jenv->GetMethodID(dClass, "<init>", "(D)V");
    if (NULL == initInt) return NULL;
    jobject newDoubleObj = jenv->NewObject(dClass, initInt, *($1.get()));

    $result = newDoubleObj;
}
```